# Jenkins in a container is much slower than on the server itself

Tags: docker, jenkins

We recently had our jenkins redone. We decided to have the new version on a docker container on the server.

While migrating, I noticed that the jenkins is MUCH slower when its in a container than when it ran on the server itself.

This is a major issue and could mess up our migration.

I tried looking for ways to give more resources to the container with not much help.

How can I speed the jenkins container/ give it all the resources it needs on the server (the server is dedicated only to jenkins).

Also, how do I devide these resources when I want to start up slave containers as well?

Comment: are you using the official Jenkins docker image, or have you built your own from scratch?

Comment: im inheriting from jenkins original and add a few things that I need (python3 and docker-compose)

Comment: could you please elaborate the "slowness". is it running slow in general or is it slow when running docker commands? I have jenkins + nexus repository containers in a 4GB RAM VPS and they work fast. note that i'm not using bind mounts. i use volumes. although it's very doable - i don't recommend to alter official jenkins image. i have default jenkins image in my container and i add my host machine as a node and perform everything on host. docker inside docker is a little bit hacky. and you will have full native resources if you add your host as a node in jenkins.

Comment: I use volumes as well. My jenkins is building and pushing docker images to out private registry so I have to add some dependencies to the base jenkins image. The building of docker images inside the container takes much longer than it did on the server itself

Comment: i'm using exactly the same scenario. with one exception. i build docker images on host via jenkins node. not inside jenkins container. and it is pretty fast.

Comment: @Yarimadam can you please expand? Do you use jenkins slave image to run this on? I would love to see your implementation if possible

Comment: I'm not using a slave image. I add my physical machine (VPS in my case) SSH details to "Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes > New Node". Then jenkins connects to my VPS server. Only dependency is to have java installed on the VPS. Jenkins puts some sort of self executable jar file to the node and executes it to connect VPS to jenkins instance (running on docker container) as a node. So docker commands in build steps getting executed at the node (VPS, physical machine) instead of jenkins docker container. I can share my screen with you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189539/discussion-between-yarimadam-and-notsoshabby).

Comment: Had same issue, one/all of below fix it:
1. uninstalled one of the plugins [working-hours-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/working-hours-plugin)
2. Upgrade Docker from V19.03.8 to V24.0.4
3. Add plugin (fix some config issues I had) - [cloudbees-jenkins-advisor](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cloudbees-jenkins-advisor/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Disk operations

One thing that can go slow with Docker is when the process running in a container is making a lot of I/O calls to the container file system. The container file system is a *union file system* which is not optimized for speed.

This is where [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) are useful. Additionally to providing a location on the file system which survives container deletion, disk performance on a docker volume is good.

The [Jenkins Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins) defines the `JENKINS_HOME` location as a docker volume, so as long as your Jenkins jobs are making their disk operations within that location you should be fine.

If you determine that disk access on that volume is still too slow, you could customize the mount location of that volume on your docker host so that it would end up being mounted on a fast drive such as a SSD.

Another trick is to make a docker volume mounted to RAM with [*tmpfs*](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/). Note that such a volume does not offer persistence and that data at that location will be lost when the container is stopped or deleted.

---

## JVM memory exhaustion / Garbage collector

As Jenkins is a Java application, another potential issue comes in mind: memory exhaustion. In the case the JVM on which the Jenkins process runs on is too limited in memory, the Java garbage collector will runs too frequently. You can witness that when you realize your Java app is using too much CPU (the garbage collector uses CPU). If that is the case, give more memory to the JVM:

```sh
docker run-p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --env JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -Djava.awt.headless=true" jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

---

## Network

Docker containers have a virtual network stack and custom network settings. You also want to make sure that all network related operation are fast.

The DNS server might be an issue, check it by executing `ping <some domain name>` from the Jenkins container.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Do you know if the container uses/ gets access to all the host's resources by default?

Comment: a docker container is by default not limited on the amount of CPU/memory/network ressources it can take from it's host. JVM max heap is however limited by default to 1/4th of your physical memory or 1GB (whichever is smaller)

Comment: Would increasing the max heap speed things up? how can I configure this in the container?

Comment: Issue in my case was plugins configuration and/or docker server ver.